which package to choose from msys2?
When I search for a package, for example, gtk4, there are many similar packages, like this:
https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=binpkg&q=gtk4
mingw-w64-clang-aarch64-gtk4    4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)
mingw-w64-clang-i686-gtk4   4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-gtk4 4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)
mingw-w64-i686-gtk4 4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gtk4  4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)
mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4   4.14.4-1    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (v4) (mingw-w64)

I'm using an intel x64 cpu, so I guess I can choose from
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-gtk4
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gtk4
mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4

the first clang I guess it's compiled by clang compiler, but what are the last 2?
ucrt, I searched a little bit, it seems to be from visual c++, so I guess it's compiler is msvc,
then, at last, what's mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4? Which one should I install?

I realized that gcc is not listed, maybe mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4 is default to gcc?

Use HolyBlackCat's answer to pick the right MSYS2 environment.  Open a shell in that environment.  Then run:
pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-gtk4


that confused me more. After installation of msys2, there are several shortcut in the start menu, differenct menu opens a console with different env, I guess. I tested, $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX is different in different console window.

Right, that's how it's supposed to work.

@FelixFXu Did you read What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?
